# How to find a game of Munchkin?

Tags: munchkin

I've been playing Munchkin for about two years.  I just moved to a new city, and now that I'm away from my friends, I've realized that not many people know the game even exists and most have no interest whatsoever. How do I go about finding people to play with?

Comment: Maybe talk to some of the people on this group: http://www.meetup.com/Valhalla-Gaming-and-Entertainment/... not a million miles away from you I think, and some of them may know somewhere even closer.

Comment: In my experience, Munchkin is how you **lose** friends, not *make* them :)

Comment: -1 - I'm not a fan of this question. To me, this seems more like a question about social skills than gaming...

Answer (score 1):

Look for stores that sell board, CCG, or role playing games.  I'd start with store finders on sites like Wizards.com. If you don't have a specialized hobby store, you can try more general stores that sell that product type such as Hastings. People at these locations might know other players, or even have places set up to play / hang out.

Check sites like Meetup and Facebook for board game groups. Also check any local universities for that type of group as well.  Sometimes you have to dig, but there are gamers out there!

Answer (score 1):

Steve Jackson Games, the makers of Munchkin, have a [Gamer Finder](http://www.sjgames.com/gamerfinder/). You can check to see if there are any stores or individuals are nearby, and even register yourself so other SJG players can find you. If you are really gung-ho about the game, you might also want to join the MIBs which is a not so secret group of gamers who run demos of Munchkin and other SJG Games at Hobby Shops and conventions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're even in a moderately urban area You should be able to find a board/tabletop/card games store, and it's not entirely rare for people to come to the store just to play non-specific board/card games.

You can probably ask the owner if he knows of such a group.  Odds are that he does.